# delete space in a column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I hope someone can help. I got the following df.

| Contact | Post Zip |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1222KH |
| 2 | 1233 MH |
| 3 | 1233 jk |

How can i make row two and three the same as row one.

So with no space between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\s+` for replace one or multiply spaces to empty string by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and then if necessary convert output to uppercase by [`Series.str.upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
df['Post Zip'] = df['Post Zip'].str.replace('\s+', '', regex=True)
print (df)
   Contact Post Zip
0        1   1222KH
1        2   1233MH
2        3   1233jk

df['Post Zip'] = df['Post Zip'].str.replace('\s+', '', regex=True).str.upper()
print (df)
   Contact Post Zip
0        1   1222KH
1        2   1233MH
2        3   1233JK
```